# Optimizing the Bounding Box Drawing in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, optimization

```
def boxDrawing(layerOutput, frameWidth, frameHeight,class_ids,confidences,boxes,img):
    for output in layerOutput:
        for detection in output:
            score = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(score)
            confidence = score[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.5:
                center_x = int(detection[0] * frameWidth)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * frameHeight)
                width = int(detection[2] * frameWidth)
                height = int(detection[3] * frameHeight)
                left = int(center_x - width / 2)
                top = int(center_y - height / 2)
                class_ids.append(class_id)
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
            boxes.append([left, top, width, height])
    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.8, 0.7)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size = (len(boxes),3))
    for i in range(len(boxes)):
        if i in indexes:
            x,y,w,h = boxes[i]
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            confi = str(round(confidences[i],2)) 
            color = colors[i]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), color,1)
            cv2.putText(img, label+" "+ confi, (x,y+20), font, 1, (255,255,255),1)
```

Here is my code to draw the bounding boxes to the detection. However, when I profile my code it seems that np.argmax(score) consumes a lot of time. Here is the cProfile output for the boxDrawing function:

```
3375   60.327    0.018  132.575    0.039 2381106525.py:39(boxDrawing)
1    0.424    0.424  742.042  742.042 2381106525.py:68(algorythmYolo)
17010000   10.916    0.000   72.061    0.000 <__array_function__ internals>:177(argmax)
17010000   20.109    0.000   47.640    0.000 fromnumeric.py:1127(argmax)
17010000    7.243    0.000   27.531    0.000 fromnumeric.py:51(_wrapfunc)
17010000   11.303    0.000   58.942    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core._multiarray_umath.implement_array_function}
17010000   17.412    0.000   17.412    0.000 {method 'argmax' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
```

The algorythmYolo is my main function which does image processing; thus, consumes the most of the time, and argmax is called only in the boxDrawing function. Is there any way to optimize boxDrawing function (thus the argmax) so that it works faster? Thanks in advance!

Comment: thresholding on detection[4] (the box score) may save you tons of argmax calls

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you classes are at the last 5 steps and that is why you gather the last 5 indices to gain the class id.

One idea would be to work the full matrix instead of indiviual 1d vectors as numpy is optimized to use matrix operations:

```
# Get the matrix of all the output classes
classes = np.array(output)[:,5:]
# class_ids returns a 1d vector with corresponding class
class_ids = np.argmax(classes, axis=1)
```

that would change your code to something like this:

```
for output in layerOutput:

    classes = np.array(output)[:,5:]
    class_ids = np.argmax(classes, axis=1)

    for index, detection in enumerate(output):
        confidence = score[class_ids[index]]
        if confidence > 0.5:
            center_x = int(detection[0] * frameWidth)
            center_y = int(detection[1] * frameHeight)
            width = int(detection[2] * frameWidth)
            height = int(detection[3] * frameHeight)
            left = int(center_x - width / 2)
            top = int(center_y - height / 2)
            class_ids.append(class_id)
            confidences.append(float(confidence))
        boxes.append([left, top, width, height])
```

Example of the slicing and maxarg:

```
import numpy as np

output = np.array([
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,2,3,4],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,2,3,4],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,2,7,4],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,2,3,4],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,6,3,4],
])

print(output)

print(output[:,5:])

classes = output[:,5:]
#[[0 0 0 2 1 2 3 4]
# [0 0 0 2 1 2 3 4]
# [0 0 0 2 1 2 7 4]
# [0 0 0 2 1 2 3 4]
# [0 0 0 2 1 6 3 4]]

print(np.argmax(classes, axis=1))
# [7 7 6 7 5]
```

Comment: Your code is giving AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1, can you review it please?

Comment: Hmm, could you please provide the `output.shape`? Seems odd that numpy thinks that it's missing a dimension. Do you have any samples where there is only one detection and thus numpy may reduce one dimension and therefore can not find axis 1 ?

Comment: Since it's a tuple it throws an error, yet it's size is changing between 20400, 81600, 326400 as the iteration continues.

Comment: To clarify, the output of the model is a tuple? I'd try to convert it to numpy rather than handling tuples. But it seems very strange that you have a very big tuple with 1d values as you slice a index. Is there a tuple with arrays within? is that correct? If that is the case i would add `np.array(output)[:,5:]` to be assigned to the variable classes.

Comment: @aec_01 Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no, sir :(

Comment: Made a clarification with an example in my previous post, check if it helps and get back to me and we'll try to solve the issue.